# Log profile 2 user info a separate log file 

Tags: users

When a user logs in, I want to log the user information from the Profile2 module in a separate file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.api.php/7 You can use `_load()` hooks and then save it to file or DB perhaps.

Comment: i am new to drupal...do i have to write a separate module for this and use _load() hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiles2 docs state:

Thanks to the foundational entity API the module integrates well with Rules as well as Features.

Install the rules module (http://drupal.org/project/rules) and you should be able to access the profile data after he user login event. To log to the system watchdog with rules you need this patch: http://drupal.org/node/1349882#comment-6190164

This does not write to a separate file, but it would be trivial to extract your entries from the watchdog db table using phpMyAdmin.

And finally it does not require any coding.

Comment: please tell me where should i add this patch. i think its related to drupal 6. i am using drupal 7

Comment: Look at the header of the issue, it gives you all the information you need. Look at the version tab of the module to find the right git commands to apply the patch.